# Is it possible to use QuestPDF Library in ASP.Net Core Web API?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to use QuestPDF in ASP.Net Core Web API. Is it Possible? I'm a beginner. I want to create a set of Questionaire with answers in the table. I created one with a console application and generated a PDF using QuestPDF with the title, logo(image), and table.

But My Question is, whether it possible in Web API? I tried searching for some reference code, but I couldn't find it. I don't know where to place my code in web API and modify it. If it is possible and if any examples are available please refer me. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use QuestPDF to generate pdfs and store as memory steram. Then in the controller you can return FileResult and pass MemeoryStream objec to it.
Consider the following steps:

1. Install QuestPDF nuget. In Solution Explorer, right-click either Solution, a project, or the References in a project, and then select Manage NuGet Packages. Search QueryPDF and Install it.
2. Generate pdfs and store in MemoryStream object or byte[].
   https://www.questpdf.com/quick-start.html
3. Return the file as pdf in the controller's action.

Code Example:

Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Controller's Action Sample Code:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public FileStreamResult GetPDF()
      {
                Document document= Document.Create(container =>
                {
                    container.Page(page =>
                    {
                        page.Size(PageSizes.A4);
                        page.Margin(2, Unit.Centimetre);
                        page.PageColor(Colors.White);
                        page.DefaultTextStyle(x => x.FontSize(20));
                        page.Header()
                            .Text("Hello PDF!")
                            .SemiBold().FontSize(36).FontColor(Colors.Blue.Medium);
    
                        page.Content()
                            .PaddingVertical(1, Unit.Centimetre)
                            .Column(x =>
                            {
                                x.Spacing(20);
    
                                x.Item().Text(Placeholders.LoremIpsum());
                                x.Item().Image(Placeholders.Image(200, 100));
                            });
    
                        page.Footer()
                            .AlignCenter()
                            .Text(x =>
                            {
                                x.Span("Page ");
                                x.CurrentPageNumber();
                            });
                    });
                });
                byte[] pdfBytes = document.GeneratePdf();
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(pdfBytes);
                return new FileStreamResult(ms, "application/pdf");
    
            }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But I'm a beginner.  so, I can't able understand sorry, can you please elaborate? OR can you please share me reference code if it is available?

Comment: Source code added to the answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I didn't get the output

Comment: I created a sample project and it works. can you share your code?

Comment: ok. I have asked a new question, I have added my code there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75793790/outputerror-net-web-api-with-questpdf-lib

Comment: Hi, I created the new controller and added the code (my code was modified as per your suggestion). But I'm getting the output in an encoded format, I couldn't figure out how to decode it. Then I added your code in the value controller, and again it is showing the output in encoded format. If you know, Please help me.

Comment: Getting encoded format means Mime type is not correct. can you share response header of result (In your browser).

Comment: Hi, are you asking for the URL? I'm not getting it. Anyway, I'm adding it, I have added your code to the value controller for that => https://localhost:44367/api/Values. I have added my code under the new controller in the name Download for that=> https://localhost:44367/api/Download . You have asked for my code it is in this link => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75793790/outputerror-net-web-api-with-questpdf-lib. I'm a beginner, so if it is wrong please let me, Thank you