# outputerror: .net web api with QuestPDF Lib

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a pdf using QuestPDF lib. in the console application, I got the output. Now, I'm trying to do the same in web API. I have created an asp.net web application(.net Framework) -> Web API. Then I created Controller with the name DownloadController and added the code [given below]. But I'm Getting output like this[Questpdf output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8sQo.png)

I couldn't figure out what I did wrong. If anyone knows help me with it. I'm a beginner at this. Thanks in advance.

````
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using QuestPDF.Fluent;
using QuestPDF.Helpers;
using QuestPDF.Infrastructure;
using SkiaSharp;

namespace Questpdf2.Controllers
{
    public class DownloadController : ApiController
    {
        [System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet]
        public FileStreamResult GetPDF()
        {
            byte[] pdfBytes = Document.Create(document =>
            {
                document.Page(page =>
                {
                    page.Margin(2, Unit.Centimetre);
                    page.DefaultTextStyle(x => x.FontSize(12));
                    page.Header()
                    .Row(row =>
                    {
                        row.Spacing(25);
                        row.ConstantItem(100)
                            .Height(100)
                            .Width(50)
                             .Image("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\HAMS\\New folder\\Questpdf2\\image\\im.png", ImageScaling.Resize);

                        row.RelativeItem()

                            .Column(column =>
                            {
                                column.Item()
                                .Text("My header")
                                .SemiBold()
                                .FontSize(30)
                                .FontColor(Colors.Blue.Medium);

                                column.Item()
                                .Text("Q&A Table")
                                .Underline()
                                .FontSize(20)
                                .FontColor(Colors.Blue.Medium);
                            });
                    });

                    page.Content()
                    .PaddingVertical(25).Table(table =>
                    {
                        table.ColumnsDefinition(columns =>
                        {
                            // s.no, question,qtype, weightage, sortorder
                            columns.ConstantColumn(50);
                            columns.RelativeColumn();
                            columns.RelativeColumn();
                            columns.ConstantColumn(60);
                            columns.ConstantColumn(60);
                        });
                        table.Header(header =>
                        {
                            header.Cell().Text("S.No");
                            header.Cell().AlignRight().Text("Question");
                            header.Cell().AlignRight().Text("QType");
                            header.Cell().AlignRight().Text("Weightage");
                            header.Cell().AlignRight().Text("Sortorder");

                        });
                        table.Cell().Text("1");
                        table.Cell().Text("what is the important aspects of IT?");
                        table.Cell().AlignRight().Text("Essay");
                        table.Cell().AlignRight().Text("5");
                        table.Cell().AlignRight().Text("6");

                        table.Cell().Text("2");
                        table.Cell().Text("an extension of image file?");
                        table.Cell().AlignRight().Text("Choice");
                        table.Cell().AlignRight().Text("2");
                        table.Cell().AlignRight().Text("1");

                        table.Cell().Text("3");
                        table.Cell().Text("What are security controls?");
                        table.Cell().AlignRight().Text("Essay");
                        table.Cell().AlignRight().Text("5");
                        table.Cell().AlignRight().Text("7");

                        table.Cell().Text("4");
                        table.Cell().Text("compliance standard?");
                        table.Cell().AlignRight().Text("Choice");
                        table.Cell().AlignRight().Text("2");
                        table.Cell().AlignRight().Text("2");

                        table.Cell().Text("5");
                        table.Cell().Text("Risk is the failure in component?");
                        table.Cell().AlignRight().Text("Choice");
                        table.Cell().AlignRight().Text("2");
                        table.Cell().AlignRight().Text("3");

                        table.Cell().Text("6");
                        table.Cell().Text("Third party tools in software?");
                        table.Cell().AlignRight().Text("Essay");
                        table.Cell().AlignRight().Text("5");
                        table.Cell().AlignRight().Text("5");

                        table.Cell().Text("7");
                        table.Cell().Text("What are cloud based solutions?");
                        table.Cell().AlignRight().Text("Essay");
                        table.Cell().AlignRight().Text("5");
                        table.Cell().AlignRight().Text("4");

                    });

                    page.Footer()
                    .AlignCenter()
                        .Text(text =>
                        {
                            text.DefaultTextStyle(x => x.FontSize(15));
                            text.Span("Page number").FontSize(10);
                            text.CurrentPageNumber();
                            text.Span(" out of ");
                            text.TotalPages();
                        });
                });
            }).GeneratePdf();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(pdfBytes);
            return new FileStreamResult(ms, "application/pdf");

        }
    }
}  ```
````

Comment: Applying System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet to an ApiController isn't correct. As the namespace suggests, that's for an MVC controller, not a Web API controller. If you were using ASP.NET Core (which you should these days), then MVC and Web API have been merged together in many respects, but not in the old ASP.NET framework. It's probably not the cause of your current issue, but you should be aware of it and correct it.

Comment: ok. thank you. I'm in the learning phase, I'll take it.